# User keeps getting a temporary profile on (initial) login in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, login, temporary-files

Here are the symptoms.

The PC is part of an AD. The user in question never had an issue until now or until a PC reinstall. When the user logs into another PC it always creates a temporary user profile. Missing network drives.

How can I fix the user profile in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can try.

1. Registry

   - Open Regedit.msc
   - Go to "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList"
   - Check for folders entries with .bak
   - If you have such entries, normally deleting them will solve this problem for you on the next login.

   Why didn't it work in my case? It was always on the initial / first login of that user. So there was no .bak file.
2. CMD

   - Run "sfc /scannow" and "DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth" in a CMD (Command Prompt) with admin rights.

   Depending on the results this might have solved your issue. For my case it was unlikely as I had just reinstalled the very same PC with Windows 10, all updates, due to another unrelated issue.
3. AD

   - Open the AD Console
   - Go to the affected user account
   - Check the "Profile path:" under "Profile"

   It's very uncommon and that might explain why you never read about it in relation to the temporary profile issue. In my case the Logon Script was listed in the Profile path, meaning on Login the PC was trying to find an entry, that didn't exist. Thereby creating a temp profile since it couldn't resolve the issue.

Comment: How is this an answer?

Comment: I not sure what you mean. It contains all the steps you need to take to solve the issue. Plus I wrote it so everyone with two brain cells should be able to understand it.